# Sticky Session on Redis of Magento2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, magento2, sticky-session

I have 2 EC2 instance of my Magento 2 store.Both is using ELB & Sticky Session.But now, i want sticky session from Redis or memcached by using another EC2 instance?
How can i achieve this & can we execute cron of my website from another instance?

Regards